# ASPNETDB.MDF for ASP.NET MVC on Production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, aspnetdb

I am getting this error when I copied my application to application folder  (I published the web application to my local IIS, then I copied to production server, this happend on production server):

The database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\TEST\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The database 'C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\TEST\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

any helps?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' was the solution...